# multiple directory size

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to get a size for a set of directories.  Currently I'm using :

`ls -d */ | du -hs > directorySizes.txt`

All I get from this is a summary of all of the directories.  I have tried `du -hc` but this gives size of each directory, including the subdirectories which I don't want.  What would the correct syntax be for what I'm looking for?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you want just the sizes (on FS) for the directories under `$PWD`?

Comment: I'm wanting the directory size for each directory under where ever I currently am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the option `--max-depth=1`. so you can just run

```
du -h --max-depth=1 > directorySizes.txt
```

I don't really think you need to run `ls` here

Comment: Thank you that's working perfectly.  I had the `ls` to only have the directories.  But the `--max-depth=1` fixes that problem.  Thank you.